# How to save date type dd/mm/yyyy format in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Tried to save date format like dd/mm/yyyy in mongodb but this is saved like 2020-06-01T18:30:00.000Z.I want to save like 2020-06-01 in mongodb.How to do it?
Here my code:

data.model.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var userSchemaData = new mongoose.Schema({
    p_id: {
        type: String
    },
    product_today: {
        type: Date
    },
    product_afterfive: {
        type: Date
    } 
}, {
    versionKey: false,
    collection: 'data'
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Data', userSchemaData);
```

data.controller.js:

```
var moment = require('moment');
var todayDate = new Date(); 
var afterfiveDays = new Date(new Date().getTime() + (5 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

module.exports.insertData = (req, res, next) => {
    let collectionName = req.query.collection;
    var Product= mongoose.model(collectionName); 
    var todayDateFormat = moment(todayDate, 'DD-MM-YYYY').format('MM-DD-YYYY');
    var afterfiveDaysFormat = moment(afterfiveDays, 'DD-MM-YYYY').format('MM-DD-YYYY');

    var product = new Product({
            p_id: "CS1",
            product_today:todayDateFormat,
            product_afterfive: afterfiveDaysFormat 
    });

        product.save(function(error, document) { 
            if (error) { console.log(error); } else {
                console.log("Successful inserted");

                res.json({ success: true, msg: 'User inserted.', cname: collectionName });
            }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the documentation, mongoose will create a native `Date` object from the provided date value (see https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/dates.html)

The reason for this is probably that MongoDB's [underlying type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#document-bson-type-date) for "date" is

> BSON Date is a 64-bit integer that represents the number of
>   milliseconds since the Unix epoch (Jan 1, 1970). This results in a
>   representable date range of about 290 million years into the past and
>   future.

so there's no date-type without the time. You can make sure in your application-code to insert dates with the time set to `00:00:00` or store the the "YYYY-MM-DD"-value as a `String` instead of a `Date`.

Comment: Hi..I have one question..I have spent lot of time to find solution but i could not..So please answer me.

Comment: I would simply change the datatype to `String` for both `product_today` and `product_afterfive` - the code you currently have for inserting can stay the same. Only if you have some logic on these date values in your app, you now need to convert the values back to a date of course.

Comment: I am talking about my new Q

Comment: Oh ok, I'll look into it.

Comment: You have any idea?

Comment: Not yet sorry :/